# Why doesn't inline editing work when there is a reportchart component?

Tags: visualforce, reporting, inlineeditsupport

I have a visualforce page that displays a report chart and and table in a tab.  In a separate tab I have a list with some data.  Inline editing is enabled for the list.  When I double click the the field I would like to edit (in this case status__c), nothing happens.  When I remove the reportchart component from the other tab, I can double click and edit just fine.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
<apex:tab label="Report">
                <apex:pageblock title="Quote Count">
                    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!summaries}" var="summary">
                        <apex:column headervalue="Sales Rep">
                            {!summary.name}<br/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headervalue="Quote Count">
                            {!summary.Quantity}
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headervalue="Total">
                           <apex:outputtext value="{0, number,$###,###,##0}"> <apex:param value="{!summary.total}"/> </apex:outputtext>
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageblocktable>
                    <analytics:reportChart reportId="00OZ0000000GcrL" size="medium"></analytics:reportChart>  <!--Breaks inline editing!!!  -->
                </apex:pageblock>
                </apex:tab>

Separate tab starts here. . .
<apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Status" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="status__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!q.Status__c}">
                <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"   <!-- Broken from reportchart in first tab -->
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputfield>
                </apex:column>

    <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" style="float:right" rerender="results"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!updatequotes}" id="saveButton" value="Save Changes" style="float:right" rerender="results"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48795/analyticsreportchart-and-inline-editing-support-not-working although even that doesn't has an answer.